# How do i get the messages from the offset in Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Binder?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am able to connect to the topic, although I am not sure on how I am able to get the messages from the topic. Here is the logs that shows that I have 1076 records on the topic:

**Logs**

```
2021-10-05 11:10:09.053  INFO 17364 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.c.s.b.k.KafkaMessageChannelBinder    : Partitions revoked: []
2021-10-05 11:10:09.054  INFO 17364 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=latest] (Re-)joining group
2021-10-05 11:10:10.063  INFO 17364 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=latest] (Re-)joining group
2021-10-05 11:10:13.189  INFO 17364 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=latest] Successfully joined group with generation 1
2021-10-05 11:10:13.205  INFO 17364 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=latest] Setting newly assigned partitions: MY_TOPIC-0
2021-10-05 11:10:13.278  INFO 17364 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=latest] Found no committed offset for partition MY_TOPIC-0
2021-10-05 11:10:13.664  INFO 17364 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.SubscriptionState    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=latest] Resetting offset for partition MY_TOPIC-0 to offset 1076.
2021-10-05 11:10:13.730  INFO 17364 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.c.s.b.k.KafkaMessageChannelBinder    : Partitions assigned: [MY_TOPIC-0]
2021-10-05 11:10:13.731  INFO 17364 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.SubscriptionState    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=latest] Seeking to EARLIEST offset of partition MY_TOPIC-0
2021-10-05 11:10:13.787  INFO 17364 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.SubscriptionState    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=latest] Resetting offset for partition MY_TOPIC-0 to offset 1076.
2021-10-05 11:46:44.345  INFO 17364 --- [thread | latest] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=latest] Group coordinator test.kafka.com:6667 (id: 2246481044 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2021-10-05 11:46:51.625  INFO 17364 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=latest] Discovered group coordinator test.kafka.com:6667 (id: 2147482644 rack: null)
2021-10-05 11:46:56.514  INFO 17364 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=latest] Attempt to heartbeat failed for since member id consumer-2-386b3e7b-b8a1-48c5-9gd3-5e587e4237ad is not valid.
2021-10-05 11:46:56.516  INFO 17364 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=latest] Revoking previously assigned partitions [MY_TOPIC-0]
2021-10-05 11:46:56.516  INFO 17364 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.c.s.b.k.KafkaMessageChannelBinder    : Partitions revoked: [MY_TOPIC-0]
2021-10-05 11:46:56.516  INFO 17364 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=latest] (Re-)joining group
2021-10-05 11:46:56.572  INFO 17364 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=latest] (Re-)joining group
2021-10-05 11:46:59.687  INFO 17364 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=latest] Successfully joined group with generation 3
2021-10-05 11:46:59.688  INFO 17364 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=latest] Setting newly assigned partitions: MY_TOPIC-0
2021-10-05 11:46:59.749  INFO 17364 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=latest] Setting offset for partition MY_TOPIC-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=1076, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=test.kafka.com:6667 (id: 1003 rack: /default-rack), epoch=2}}
2021-10-05 11:46:59.812  INFO 17364 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.c.s.b.k.KafkaMessageChannelBinder    : Partitions assigned: [MY_TOPIC-0]
```

**Consumer Class**

```
public interface EventConsumer {

    @Input("my-group-id")
    SubscribableChannel consumeMessage();

}
```

**Listener Class**

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableBinding(EventConsumer.class)
public class EventListener {

     @StreamListener(target = "my-group-id")
     public void processMessage(Object msg) {
         log.info("*** MESSAGE: ***", msg);
         **do something**
         **save messages**
     }
}
```

**Application.yml**

```
kafka:
    consumer:
      properties:
        max.poll.interval.ms: 3600000
      max-poll-records: 10
  cloud:
    zookeeper:
      connect-string: test.kafka.com:2181,test.kafka.com:2181,test.kafka.com:2181
    stream:
      kafka:
        bindings:
          my-group-id:
            consumer:
              autoCommitOffset: false
        binder:
          brokers:
            - test.kafka.com:6667
            - test.kafka.com:6667
            - test.kafka.com:6667
          auto-create-topics: false
          auto-add-partitions: false
          jaas:
            controlFlag: REQUIRED
            loginModule: com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule
            options:
              useKeyTab: true
              storeKey: true
              serviceName: kafka
              keyTab: C:\\files\\user.keytab
              principal: user@test.com
              debug: true
          configuration:
            security:
              protocol: SASL_PLAINTEXT
      bindings:
        my-group-id:
          binder: kafka
          destination: MY_TOPIC
          group: test-kafka-service
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 50MB
      max-request-size: 50MB
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.my-group-id.consumer.resetOffsets: true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.commit.interval.ms: 300000
```

Upon reading the logs, it does not even go to my listener class wherein I placed a logger for it. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a `@StreamListener` to start again at the beginning of the log, configure a `group` on the binding (so that auto.offset.reset gets set to `earliest` and set `resetOffsets` to `true`.

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.my-group-id.consumer.resetOffsets=true
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.4/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-consumer-properties

> **resetOffsets**

> Whether to reset offsets on the consumer to the value provided by startOffset. Must be false if a `KafkaBindingRebalanceListener` is provided; see Using a KafkaBindingRebalanceListener. See Resetting Offsets for more information about this property.

> Default: false.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.4/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#reset-offsets

**EDIT**

It works fine for me:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So69432739Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So69432739Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<String> input() {
        return System.out::println;
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaOperations<byte[], byte[]> ops) {
        return args -> {
            ops.send("input-in-0", "one".getBytes());
            ops.send("input-in-0", "two".getBytes());
            ops.send("input-in-0", "three".getBytes());
        };
    }

}
```

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input-in-0.group=grp
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input-in-0.consumer.reset-offsets=true
```

The second time I ran it:

```
one
two
three
one
two
three
```

```
Setting offset for partition input-in-0-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=3, ...
Resetting offset for partition input-in-0-0 to position FetchPosition{offset=0, ...
```

Note that I am using the newer functional style (`@StreamListener` is deprecated); although that makes no difference to this functionality.

**EDIT2**

You can't mix propertie and YAML like that; I copied your YAML (commenting out some that I don't need) and it works fine...

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      properties:
        max.poll.interval.ms: 3600000
      max-poll-records: 10
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        bindings:
          my-group-id:
            consumer:
              autoCommitOffset: false
              reset-offsets: true
#        binder:
#          brokers:
#            - test.kafka.com:6667
#            - test.kafka.com:6667
#            - test.kafka.com:6667
#          auto-create-topics: false
#          auto-add-partitions: false
#          jaas:
#            controlFlag: REQUIRED
#            loginModule: com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule
#            options:
#              useKeyTab: true
#              storeKey: true
#              serviceName: kafka
#              keyTab: C:\\files\\user.keytab
#              principal: user@test.com
#              debug: true
#          configuration:
#            security:
#              protocol: SASL_PLAINTEXT
      bindings:
        input-int-0:
          binder: kafka
          destination: input-in-0
          group: test-kafka-service
#  servlet:
#    multipart:
#      max-file-size: 50MB
#      max-request-size: 50MB
```

```
Setting offset for partition input-in-0-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=6 ...
Seeking to EARLIEST offset of partition input-in-0-0
Resetting offset for partition input-in-0-0 to position FetchPosition{offset=0 ...
```

Comment: hello, i got this from the logs "Seeking to EARLIEST offset of partition MY_TOPIC-0" and "Resetting offset for partition MY_TOPIC-0 to offset 1076." although I haven't seen a log where it passed by the processMessage method.

Comment: Edit the question to show the new configuration as well as the new logs.

Comment: It works fine for me (see example); I suspect you ignored my comment about adding a `group` to the binding - bindings without a group use the `latest` `auto.offset.reset` property.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the logs and added the yml config. Is the one that I added under bindings the one you're referring to?

Comment: You are using YAML - you can't mix YAML and properties. See the second edit.